# Files saved in device internal memory getting cleared when the application is closed from multitask window in Android OS 4.2.2

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Our app saves application data to internal memory using the Context.getDir(foldername,Context.MODE_READABLE | Context.MODE_WRITABLE). The app data works fine on all platform except Android Samsung Galaxy Nexus 4.2.2 and Google Nexus 4.2.2, when the application is closed from the multi task window, by swiping the application out from current running application list. If the appllication is exited normally, by pressing back, back.. button the app data does not get affected.
We tried the same steps on HTC One 4.0.3, but the issue is not reproducible and the app data does not get cleared when the application is removed from currently running list from the multi task app running view. I have debugged a lot, I couldn't find any issue with the code. All the file streams are closed properly.  Also when we set the following setting under developer option, Background process limit to No Background processes, the app data is not getting cleared on Samsung Galaxy Nexus 4.2.2 and Google Nexus 4.2.2.
If we set the Background process Limit  back to Standard Limit and Close our application from  Multi task application View on the device homescreen, the App data gets cleared, hence all the information of the user gets cleared.
Our application has multiple activities, When the Application is send to background by pressing Home Button from the Launcher Activity, and then closing the Application from Multi Tasking Window View, the App data does not cleared and the issue is not reproducible on Samsung Galaxy Nexus 4.2.2 and Google Nexus 4.2.2.
But when the Application moves away from Launcher Activity to other Activity of our Application and then our Application is sent to background, by pressing Home Button and then closing our application from Multi Tasking Window from the Device Homescreen, the Files saved using Context.getDir(foldername,Context.MODE_READABLE | Context.MODE_WRITABLE) is getting cleared.
I also tried to reproduce this issue on Android Emulator 4.2.2, but it is not reproducible and it is working perfectly.
I am not sure why the internal memory files are getting cleared by the OS and how is it related to the Limit Background Process, as our application is working perfectly with No Background processes, but it is getting cleared in case of Standard Limit which is the Factory Settings in all Devices.

Comment: Consider using run-as from the adb shell with a debug version of your app (or DDMS in the emulator) to monitor the actual file.  The important question would be if it is being cleared by the platform, or if your app is dying in an odd state while trying to update the file.

Comment: With the latest os you cant see the files in the internal memory. I debugged by printing the file inputstream available size before the app is killed by multitask window. Before the app is close from multitask window the file inputstream available size is around 4000, after closing the app from multitasak window and after restarting the app the file inputstream available size changes to 56, hence all the information saved in file is cleared

Comment: When the steps are followed in android os 4.0.3, there is no issue and even when we chaange the limit background process from standard to 1 one process from device settings developer option,  in 4.2.2 there is no issue.

Comment: run-as still works to access private files of a debug apk in the latest android release.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I verified on 4.2.2 emulator, the issue is not reproducible, the file size remains unchanged after terminating the application from multi tasking application window, it is reproducible on Samsung Galaxy Nexus 4.2.2. and Google Nexus 4.2.2 Phones