# How to use android.permission.SET_PROCESS_LIMIT

Tags: android

How can  I use `android.permission.SET_PROCESS_LIMIT` permision the set the process limit for the application.

In Android Developer Option user can user can set the permission Limit Background Process to standar, No process, etc
How can we set this settings from the application?

Comment: Since that permission cannot be held by normal Android apps (`android:protectionLevel="signature|system|development"`), most likely you cannot use `SET_PROCESS_LIMIT`.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a small android app that can be used to set the process limit. Due to the android permission system you need to install it as a priviledged system app on Android 4.2+. Therefore, you need root on your device.

https://github.com/flode/SetAndroidProcessLimit

Answer (score 0):

Please set permision in maneafiest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_PROCESS_LIMIT" />
```

Comment: Could you reduce the manifest to a minimal state? The activities for Twitter are not important for this answer...

Comment: only add this line in manifeast file :<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_PROCESS_LIMIT" />

Comment: There is no reason to comment with the same content as the answer... I mean, why?!

Comment: I am looking for this because, I have one issue which I have filed on stack overflow, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17455459/files-saved-in-device-internal-memory-getting-cleared-when-the-application-is-cl . So I think, If i can change the limit, I might resolve the issue

Comment: Warren, can you please explain, what do you mean by reducing the manifest to minimal state ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tasker for this:

> The required permission is already integrated into Tasker, but you
> will need to grant it manually. Use the following cmd to do so:
>
> `pm grant net.dinglisch.android.taskerm android.permission.SET_PROCESS_LIMIT`
>
> As the value will be restored after rebooting the device, you will
> need to automate it on device boot.
>
> Standard process limit (-1) could be 10, 15, 20, or whatever the
> Android manages in the background. In depends on your system.
>
> Even 1, 2, 3 or 4 are the only available options to be chosen from
> settings (Developer Options), you can specify any other value higher
> than 4 if want too. (But, doing so will make the custom values not to
> be reflected on its settings, only visible by this task)

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/cn5ufe/task_toggle_androids_background_process_limit/